# How to select an option from a drop down?

Tags: webdriver

When I'm trying to select any one of the options from a drop down "Birthday" on Google account creation page using `.xpath`, I found the xpath as follows:

`.//*[@id=':a']` but it was not selecting the desired option the drop down. But, when I added /div at the end of the same xpath i.e `.//*[@id=':a']/div` it worked.

Can anyone explain why I should add /div at the end?

Comment: Bear in mind that "ASAP" is a good way to have your post downvoted - please don't do it `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

It was happened because your proper Element is `//*[@id=':a']/div` not just `//*[@id=':a']`

See the image below :-

[image]